# Complex number in a 3x3 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, systems-of-equations

[image]

To calculate this should I multiply conjugate of complex number?
If I should I have no idea how to start...

Thanks

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) to format your posts.

Answer (score 2):

Just use your usual methods of solving linear systems of equations, but using arithmetic of complex numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the inverse of 
$M= \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 1 & 1  \\
    0 & 2 & 1  \\
    1 & i & 1
  \end{bmatrix}$.

$M^{-1} =  \begin{bmatrix}
   (8+i)/13 & (-5+i)/13 &(-3-2i)/13  \\
(3+2i)/13 &(3+2i)/13 &(-6-4i)/13  \\
(-6-4i)/13 &(7-4i)/13 &(12+8i)/13
  \end{bmatrix}$.

And the solution is $M^{-1}  \begin{bmatrix}
   3+3i \\
5+i  \\
1+4i
  \end{bmatrix} = 
 \begin{bmatrix} x = i \\
  y = 2 \\
z = 1+i\end{bmatrix}
$.